# When to ask for push notifications?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

My app is a goal-setting workshop. The user describes his life goals, and then the software sends him reminders on important dates.

Apple suggests, that I should ask the user to allow me to send push notifications at the app launch, but I don't like it. I would like to register for push notifications *after* the user has completed the workshop.

My reasoning is that if the user gets to know how good the app is, and the app informs him why he is asked for push notif. access, he will be more inclined to accept the request.

Is my reasoning correct? And - are there any stats on how many users generally subscribe to push notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merlin, I actually prefer your strategy.  When I first launch an app, I'd like to know what it plans to do with the permissions I give it.  And I'm much more likely to grant permissions to an app if I trust it to use those permissions for *my* benefit, rather than its own.

So if I can use the app *without* granting it any special permissions beyond those that are absolutely necessary, I can make an informed decision about whether it suits my needs.  If I complete your workshop, and I feel it's valuable to me, then I'll happily ask for push notifications.  An app that asks immediately for fairly invasive permissions makes me uncomfortable in a "used-car salesman" sort of way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I can see that we agree. I wonder though if there are any (technical?) downsides to this approach.

Comment: I don't see any downside, as long as you're transparent about _asking_ for permission before you _use_ that permission.  Can anyone else offer a different perspective?

Comment: the only downside i see, is maybe missing the one opportunity you got , since the user might close your app before he finishes the workshop and then you miss the option to remind him that the app exists in the future.